# Woocommerce - How can I create an order form/quote to be added to a cart?

Tags: forms, woocommerce, form-submit, wordpress

I'm working for a client who prints on canvases, he needs the site to request the user's information/preferences of what kind of print job is to be done.

The user fills a form attaching an image of what should be printed on a canvas with predefined prices for different canvases or print surfaces of different sizes, on submission of the form, the fields of the form are transferred to the cart.

When an order has been placed, the user can checkout by paying for the products once ready.

I'm trying to recreate the order form here nifty250.co.za at the bottom of the page, exempting the Instagram login part.

I'm aware of a plugin like Gravity form with an add-on that might be able to do this, but I'm not sure it can do as I intend.

Comment: I've seen several Request for Quote style plugins in the market. Would any of those work? Otherwise, you could be looking at some very custom coding. I've been interested in an order now/pay later client-created system for a while, but haven't really done any work on it.

Answer (score -1):

Products are actually a custom post type, so you can use wp_insert_post to insert a new product. After you insert, you get the id of the new product post type, use update_post_meta to set a meta key and meta value as _visibility and visible respectively. you can set the visibility also.

This answer shows how to [insert product](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137501/how-to-add-product-in-woocommerce-with-php-code) .
To add to cart

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant to this question at all, perhaps you posted in the wrong place.